# CE button of calculator is not working properly

Tags: javascript, html, css

CE button of my calculator is not working,it just clears all numbers on clicking CE button.I just want that on clicking CE button,it only delete last number and not all numbers and one more thing when the calculator load it will show default 0 value and when any number entered 0 will replace with that number

```html
<html>
        <head>
        <title>Calculator
        </title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
        </head>
        <body>
        <center>
        
        <form name="calculator">
        <div style=" width: 200px;height: 250px;border: 1px solid #D0CECE;">
        
        <table  style="margin-top:20px;">
        <tr>
        <td>
        <input name="displayresult"  id="display" class="cal-input" disabled >
        </td>
        </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0px" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-top:5px;">
        
        <tr>
        <td name="left" value="(" onclick="calculator.display.value += '('" class="cal-top">(</td>
        <td name="right" value=")" onclick="calculator.display.value += ')'" class="cal-top"> )</td>
        <td class="operator cal-top" name="percent" value="%" onclick="calculator.display.value += '%'">%</td>
        <td id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="calculator.display.value = ''" class=" cal-top">CE</td>
        
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" class="cal-number">7</td>
        <td name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'" class="cal-number">8</td>
        <td name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'" class="cal-number">9</td>
        <td class="operator cal-top" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'">/</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'" class="cal-number">4</td>
        <td name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'" class="cal-number">5</td>
        <td name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'" class="cal-number">6</td>
        <td class="operator cal-top" name="times" value="*" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'">*</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'" class="cal-number">1</td>
        <td name="two" value="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'" class="cal-number">2</td>
        <td name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'" class="cal-number">3</td>
        <td class="operator cal-top" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'">-</td>
        </tr>
        
        <tr>
        <td name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'" class="cal-number">0</td>
        <td name="decimal" value="." onclick="calculator.display.value += '.'" class="cal-number">.</td>
        <td name="result" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)" class="cal-result"><b>=</b></td>
        <td class="operator cal-top" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'">+</td>
        </tr>
        
        </table>
        </div>
        </form>
        
        
        </center>
        </body>
        </head>
        </html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change the `CE` button `onclick` function to the following:

```
onclick="str = calculator.display.value.slice(0, -1);calculator.display.value = str;"
```

Which gets the value of the calculator output, and removes the last character from it and puts that in a variable named `str`, and then sets the calculator output to the value of `str`.

Then add `placeholder="0"` to the `<input>` which displays the calculator output:

```
<input name="displayresult" id="display" class="cal-input" placeholder="0" disabled>
```

Which makes the `<input>` display the value `0` when it contains nothing, and it goes away when characters are added to the box.

```html
<html>

<head>
  <title>Calculator
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="index.css">
</head>

<body>
  <center>

    <form name="calculator">
      <div style=" width: 200px;height: 250px;border: 1px solid #D0CECE;">

        <table style="margin-top:20px;">
          <tr>
            <td>
              <input name="displayresult" id="display" class="cal-input" placeholder="0" disabled>
            </td>
          </tr>
        </table>
        <table border="0px" cellspacing="10px" style="margin-top:5px;">

          <tr>
            <td name="left" value="(" onclick="calculator.display.value += '('" class="cal-top">(</td>
            <td name="right" value=")" onclick="calculator.display.value += ')'" class="cal-top"> )</td>
            <td class="operator cal-top" name="percent" value="%" onclick="calculator.display.value += '%'">%</td>
            <td id="clear" name="clear" value="c" onclick="str = calculator.display.value.slice(0, -1); calculator.display.value = str" class=" cal-top">CE</td>

          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td name="seven" value="7" onclick="calculator.display.value += '7'" class="cal-number">7</td>
            <td name="eight" value="8" onclick="calculator.display.value += '8'" class="cal-number">8</td>
            <td name="nine" value="9" onclick="calculator.display.value += '9'" class="cal-number">9</td>
            <td class="operator cal-top" name="div" value="/" onclick="calculator.display.value += '/'">/</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td name="four" value="4" onclick="calculator.display.value += '4'" class="cal-number">4</td>
            <td name="five" value="5" onclick="calculator.display.value += '5'" class="cal-number">5</td>
            <td name="six" value="6" onclick="calculator.display.value += '6'" class="cal-number">6</td>
            <td class="operator cal-top" name="times" value="*" onclick="calculator.display.value += '*'">*</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td name="one" value="1" onclick="calculator.display.value += '1'" class="cal-number">1</td>
            <td name="two" value="2" onclick="calculator.display.value += '2'" class="cal-number">2</td>
            <td name="three" value="3" onclick="calculator.display.value += '3'" class="cal-number">3</td>
            <td class="operator cal-top" name="minus" value="-" onclick="calculator.display.value += '-'">-</td>
          </tr>

          <tr>
            <td name="zero" value="0" onclick="calculator.display.value += '0'" class="cal-number">0</td>
            <td name="decimal" value="." onclick="calculator.display.value += '.'" class="cal-number">.</td>
            <td name="result" value="=" onclick="calculator.display.value = eval(calculator.display.value)" class="cal-result"><b>=</b></td>
            <td class="operator cal-top" name="plus" value="+" onclick="calculator.display.value += '+'">+</td>
          </tr>

        </table>
      </div>
    </form>


  </center>
</body>
</head>

</html>
```

Comment: in this code,i also want to validate it in such a way that the first number entered must be a digit and after that only one operator can be entered....

Comment: @BhaweshBhaskar It's probably better if you ask another question instead of adding on to this one.

Answer (score 0):

You can apply simple maths for this.Division and multiplication of 10
**For CE**: Take the number divide it by 10 and return the integer.
Ex: you pressed 103 already and now you click on CE.
    now 103/10 = 10(in integer).
 **For 0 Replacement**:the same reverse logic you can apply for the replacement of default zero by a number pressed
Ex:It is displaying 0 initially now you press 2
   0(old value)*10+2(new key pressed)= 2
   after you press 6
   2(old value)*10+6(new key pressed)= 26